# Unable to connect model to user in django

Tags: django, django-models

So i have a model called folder, i want to show all the folder created by current user on HomeView, but somehow it's not working, what i think is that folders are not getting connected to user who created them.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

# The Folders Model.

class Folder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete = CASCADE, null = True, blank = True )
    cr_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(to=User, on_delete=CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name
```

**view.py**
class HomeView(TemplateView):
template_name = "ahmed_drive/home.html"

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    user = self.request.user
    home_folders = Folder.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-cr_date')
    home_files = Fileshare.objects.filter(uploaded_by=user).order_by('-id')
    context['home_folders'] = home_folders
    context['home_files'] = home_files
    return context



@method_decorator(login_required, name="dispatch")    
class FolderCreate(CreateView):
    model = Folder
    fields = ["name", "parent"]
    def formvalid():
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home.html')
        else :
            return render(request,{'form': form})
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

{% for Folder in home_folders %}
<h1> {{Folder.name}} </h1>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: show code where you create new folder

Comment: @AndreyMaslov hi, i have edited my question with the createview of folder please have a look

Answer (score 0):

when you create folder you don't connect user to it.
you need to do it before saving form

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    folder = form.save(commit=False)
    folder.user = request.user
    folder.save()
    return redirect('home.html')
```